# Screen has a black border?

Tags: windows, display, resolution, vga, border

Basically, when I was going to change my screen brightness, I accidentally hit the "auto" button next to the "Menu" button. It changed my screen resolution and I can't fix it. I tried shifting the screen with the NVIDIA control panel, but the screen goes into the black border rather than pushing onto the black border. I tried pressing "auto" again but nothing is happening. I don't know anything about PCs so this is very frustrating. I use VGA and a windows 10. Please send any solutions for this.

Comment: Get a full screen image of something white (use http://www.whitedisplay.com/ and click the "expand" icon). Then press the Auto button again. VGA tries to work out where your image is according to where bright images are and having any area of darkness can make the detection go very wrong. Windows having a dark taskbar does not help.

Comment: @Mokubai It somewhat worked, the right side border is gone, but the left and top side border is still there. The right side of the screen is being cut off slightly because there isn't enough room (I think).

Comment: Repeat it a few times. Pressing auto can be a bit of a hit and miss. Also try to reboot and press auto a few times during that, and if that doesn't work, turning the screen on and off and then repeating the above may also work.